# http //tempuri.org/ in Web services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am working on webservices. but i dont understand why does http://tempuri.org exist.i have go through some of the articles and came to know that it is used for uniqueness. when i click on that link it is redirecting to bing.

Plese explain how does it works? why it is not used in WCF?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempuri)

> Each XML Web service needs a unique namespace in order for client applications to distinguish it from other services on the Web.
>   **tempuri.org is the test default namespace URI used by Microsoft development products**, like Visual Studio. It is available for XML Web services that are under development, but published XML Web services should use a more permanent namespace. The term is strictly a placeholder and all instances of it should be replaced with a more meaningful URI in production systems.

Since Microsoft owns tempuri.org, but it's only intended as a placeholder, they figured they would redirect it to a site they actually want you to use.

Comment: I always thought it was for crispy fried Japanese vegetables until I realised it was `temp uri`

Answer (score 2):

Setting Namespace on WorkflowServiceBehavior should definetly work,unless someother part of code is resetting it to null through servicedescription.Namespace but I will validate it. But to unblock you please try the following.

workflowServiceHost.Description.Namespace = "";; and see it works for you?

Nazim Ali

Answer (score 0):

It's the default namespace used for schema and metadata documents when you do not explicitly specify one yourself. For example, when u mark a class with the `DataContract` attribute bur don't supply a value for the `Namespace` property. Same goes for an `OperationContract`, `MessageContract`, etc.