# Why chaninging tempui.org in wsdl made my service work?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, asmx

I have a soap web service which is working ok on the local server but not accessible from the outside and fails with the error that HTTP header not found.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="http://tempui.org">
```

but when I use

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="https:www.mycompanydomainname.org/">
```

It works.

The only different is that I put instead of `xmlns:urn="http://tempui.org">` this, I put this `xmlns:urn="https:www.mycompanydomainname.org/"`

And it started working.

Why?

Comment: Is it `http://tempui.org` or `http://tempuri.org/`?

Comment: Because if it's `tempuri.org` then this is Microsoft's temporary default namespace for services under development, see [What is tempuri.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180985/3744182) and [http //tempuri.org/ in Web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21771072/3744182).  Possibly when your code is merged into your production server it gets replaced with your organization's required namespace.